# How to interact with Calendar in Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to input date of birth in calendar but every time it's showing element is not interactable. I already tried below options.

**Code**:

Set Focus To Element    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input

```
   ${Horizontal}=   Get Horizontal Position    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input

   ${Vertical}=    Get Vertical Position    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input

                            Input Text    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input    1993-10-14

        ${year}     ${month}    ${day}=     Evaluate    "1993-10-14".split("-")

    ${day}  ${month}    ${year}=    Evaluate    "14/10/1993".split("/")

      Click Element At Coordinates    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[6]/div/input  472  301

      **Output**:
```

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4owH9.png)